# Как преобразовать #000 или black в цвет? Javascript/React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

С сервера мне приходят разные цвета в виде hex #000 или в виде слова black. Как мне преобразовать это в визуальный цвет. Буду благодарен за помощь

Comment: А что вы подразумеваете под "визуальным" цветом? Вам нужно преобразовать hex в rgb? Окарсить кнопку? Непонятно...

Comment: Я пишу магазин на React мне атрибуты приходят с Apollo в виде #000 или как слово black (или любой другой цвет), я хочу что бы оно отображалась не как слово black или #000 , а как сам цвет черный

Comment: Где отображалось? Что отображалось? Что ты хочешь сделать чёрным (например) кнопку, рамку, квадратик-образец цвета товара?

Comment: Квадратик образца цвета товара, сейчас это выглядит как 

<div style={border: 1px  solid black}>Black</div>

Это код для примера, что бы было понимание. Реально вместо Black передаются разные данные для каждого товара свои. С функционалом у меня нет проблем, только что бы React понимал что слово black или hex #000 нужно преобразовать в цвет черный

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const exampleColor = "#000" || "black";

<div style={{ border: `1px solid ${exampleColor}`, color: exampleColor }}>Black</div>
```

Comment: Здравствуйте, я немного переделал и на основе вашего ответа все получилось, благодарю за помощь!

Comment: Очень рад помочь)

Comment: У меня есть еще одна ветка вопроса по Pagination с Apollo(GraphQl) на React. Я с GraphQl начал знакомится на проекте над которым сейчас работаю. Мне нужно сделать Pagination для классовых компонентов (все приложение на классовых компонентах), если хотите и знаете как помочь, то буду рад)) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1406719/pagination-%d0%bd%d0%b0-react-apollo